# How do you challenge the closing of one of your questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

As a newcomer to StackOverflow, I recently asked my first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438408/do-you-ask-questions-on-sites-like-so-immediately-or-organise-them-first). I wanted to start with a fairly safe general question, to get the feel for how the site worked. My question was intended to be programming-related, but my original wording was not clear enough, so another user decided to close it.

I've re-phrased my question, and had received one useful answer before the question was closed, but I'm not sure what the procedure is after your question is closed to allow people to post answers again...

I've checked the FAQ and About pages, searched the SO questions, but have had no luck. Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I get my question re-opened, or if it is possible to do at all?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: Ask in the comments for someone with sufficient rep to reopen. You can't reopen your own question. 

PS this is non-programming related, please will someone with rep close?

;-)

Comment: @Sam: good tip, thanks. I was aware I couldn't re-open my own question, but there was no information on how to handle a closed question if you wanted it re-opened.

Comment: As the owner of the question, you can cast one vote for it to be reopened, if you have enough rep (250). You're just shy.

Comment: Why is this tagged [meta-tag:faq] when the question is not answered?

Answer (score 15):

Editing your question will bring it back into view. If you edit in a well thought out request for re-open and those with re-open powers agree with it, it will get re-opened.

I suggest the comments section on your post are the right place to discuss the arguments for opening/closing.

You can also go to your site's Meta and open a question about it to get further input, and *possibly* get other people to vote to reopen your question if it was wrongly closed.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, there is no real procedure. But there are some guidelines:

To keep a question open:

- Keep the question on topic (programming in this case)
- Search for duplicates
- Mind your language and attitude
- Show your effort sofar and don't ask to give a complete solution (we won't do your homework).
- If the question is slightly off topic, make it a community wiki.

To reopen a question:

- read the comments, there is possibly an hint
- edit your question and ask for reopening
- have a bit of patience ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leaving the corpse of your dead question to cool and start another question that benefits from what you learned from the demise of your original question.

(Sorry about the unfortunate metaphor, it's Monday morning GMT)

Comment: Lol, happy monday morning ;-).

Comment: It appears this question is even less popular than the last :) thanks for your answer, I'll limit my questions to more specific programming topics in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Although I should close this question, I'll cut you some slack first ;)

Your previous question, like this one are the type of questions that are bound to get closed, because they aren't UNDENIABLY programming related. Now of course on SO, there are many questions that are very dubiously programming related, but then your stepping into the realm of luck, you might get a few gold medals (just ask Bill the Lizard) or down-voted and closed.