# What should be done with a closed question that has been completely rewritten?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859794/classification-with-deal-bayes-network) was originally a closed as "not constructive"- in its [original form](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13859794/1), it was asking which of three R machine learning packages was best.

The author has since edited the question so that it has almost nothing in common with the original, except that both involve machine learning in R. The new question, about a specific error in the `deal` package, is answerable and on-topic (thought it might deserve a bit of editing).

I've seen discussion of [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) before, but that usually concerns the case where open questions have been answered and the user is changing them in response to answers.

The right thing in this case would have been to for the user to ask a new question, but given that he hasn't, should the question be reopened, or the edit rolled back and the user encouraged to ask a new question?

(It's also possible, though far from apparent, that the user could be question-banned, and editing his old questions as a way of circumventing the ban).

Comment: I've seen this happen a number of times with users who are question-banned.

Comment: Mere seconds after I asked this question, the same user asked his question [again on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165200/classification-with-deal-bayes-network), which does increase the likelihood he is question banned (or at least not overly familiar with the site's rules).

Comment: It's a not-_altogether_-unreasonable interpretation of the "Edit your old questions to improve them" advice. The new version of the question is likely something I'd vote to close, too, however.

Comment: I had [a case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964070/)  where the question was closed. It seems that if a user has only a few points although [he intends to change his own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964070/#comment-17756291) & [grey about box](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1757431/acannan) he is unable to do so.
The procedure to [edit and reopen your own closed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19128/201728) is [too hidden](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+closed-questions) for newbies.
@bill-the-lizard Could you help out in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a tough one.  If there had been any answers I would definitely say this was not cool at all.  However, he *was* told to edit his existing closed questions to make them fit into the site guidelines. (He very likely *is* question banned, based on deleted questions.)

I'm inclined to let this one slide.  This user has three open questions at the moment.  If any of those are edited into completely new questions, we'll know for certain that this is an attempt to circumvent the ban.  Until then, I'm willing to give him the benefit of the doubt.

Update: I now notice that the user did make small changes to two of those questions about an hour ago.  These look like attempts to improve the existing questions.

Comment: Do moderators not have the ability to tell for sure if a user is question-banned?

Comment: @DavidRobinson No, the only additional information that we have on that is that we can see deleted posts in everyone's profile.

Comment: I wonder if that's a worthwhile feature (wouldn't some moderator decisions, like banning a user on Meta for asking programming questions there to circumvent a question ban, be helped by the information?) In any case, your answer sounds right, and I'm glad the question is reopened

Answer (score 0):

> Well... If you're circumventing the ban by turning bad questions into good ones... Mission Accomplished! – [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165199/what-should-be-done-with-a-closed-question-that-has-been-completely-rewritten#comment482215_165201)

That is the goal of every ounce of the system: make you create better content. If the question is closed, then any attempt to put it in a good standing should be welcomed and accepted. If there are answers, they should be just deleted. They were answering a subpar question anyways, so it's very unlikely that the answers would be any different.

Comment: Changing a bad question into a completely different good question is not something that should be encouraged. The new content should be posted as a new question, and not burdened with irrelevant history, creation date, comments, flags, etc.  If that is the only way for someone to get out from under a question ban, then we should rethink that, not encourage people to invalidate answers. I have seen very useful answers to closed questions and I don’t agree that we can assume a poorly asked question always produces poorly written answers.

Comment: @ColleenV the example in this case does *not* invalidate existing answers. If it isn't invalidating existing answers... no harm is occurring? You could consider it a way of circumventing the question ban, but if the end result is a good question and no answers are invalidated, why not? There's no harm in deleting awful answers.

Comment: @ColleenV [citation needed] Shog was all for it. Why aren't you? Why should OP have a indelible question that noone wants, nor the OP, nor the community. It's as if people can't redeem themselves.