# How to get a Question OFF hold?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed, on-hold

There is [one question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172674/why-do-first-person-shooters-seem-prefer-to-save-at-checkpoints-instead-of-at-my) which got on hold, where the reason is not really plausible for me and it would be a good discussion and I would like to answer it but I can't find a button to ask for "off hold" or anything. I can't even comment the On-Hold info since I am too new.

Comment: Please provide a link to the question. You did notice that the on-hold reason has a link that explains why it was put on-hold? You did notice that the site have a [help] that contains loads of guidance and that each site has a meta site with a search function that would give, if used, one or two results of questions asked before this one with accepted answer(s)....

Comment: [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172674/why-do-first-person-shooters-seem-prefer-to-save-at-checkpoints-instead-of-at-my] That is the question. It's a game question and for me it is a very good question and perfectly fits there.

Comment: I'd say this belongs on that site's meta since they are the only ones that can provide specific guidance on that specific question, but since you don't have the minimum 5 rep to post on Meta.Arqade, that would be difficult for you to achieve.

Comment: But given a mod closed that question and the question appears to be about UX of a game's design, then the close reason would appear correct (although, I don't particpate in Arqade or GameDev, so I could be wrong).

Comment: @Exportforce I have nothing to add to that close reason and I doubt it will get reopened.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/how-do-you-challenge-the-closing-of-one-of-your-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People who can put a question on hold (namely, people with 3,000 reputation and moderators) also have the ability to <kbd>reopen</kbd> a question which is on-hold. It also takes 5 votes (or one moderator's vote).

This question is likely better posted on your site's meta. Namely **[Gaming Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/)**

Answer (score 4):

That question was closed specifically because it's looking for developer reasoning.  Since we're not the developers who made Wolfenstein, there's nothing we can use in our expertise to actually answer the question.

Even in the general sense, since the asker wants to know why modern FPS games are programmed that way, we still can't answer it.  Our expertise is focused on *playing* games.  Not dissecting them, and not reading the minds of those who made them.

These questions are off-topic, and we have a category just for them: "Game design and development".  We don't allow questions asking, "Why did they design it that way.", for the reasons listed above.

Comment: Must every question lead to a perfect answer? Some things should be something to be albe to talk about and that one is a very good question... But if it is only for questions about the "ultimate" possible answer, almost 90% of all questions would need to be closed... Sure it is not about "gameplay" or stuff but still deserves to be in a gaming area.

Comment: @export, [Stack Exchange is not the place for conversation, opinions, or socializing](http://stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @export Arqade has a strict focus on what we allow. Yes, we're the gaming site for SE, but that doesn't mean any question about games are allowed. A good rule of thumb is: if it happens in-game, we're good. If not, chances are good it doesn't belong.

Comment: Erm but saving or checkpoints are ingame happening stuff. Some games have one, some games the other and less games have even both. @fbueckert

Comment: @Export but the point is there is no answer to that question that is on-topic for that site . You want to participate in a discussion and no matter the quality of the question, discussions are not acceptable on any SE sites (except meta sites)

Comment: @export What is being asked for isn't knowledge that can be gleaned from in-game. It requires in depth developer knowledge to answer. We might get lucky, and find a Dev talk about it, but that knowledge still doesn't come from our expertise. It comes from random web browsing, not playing games. Therefore, it doesn't play to our expertise in any sense.