# Unclear how to unhold an "on hold" question

Tags: discussion, support, on-hold

This question is related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234047/how-to-get-a-question-off-hold) question about on hold.

As it is, the "On Hold" explanation just says "edit your question or leave a comment". I thought it was odd that doing that would "unhold" the question, but I followed the instructions anyway... and, of course, nothing happened.

I just spent 10 minutes reading DIY.stackexchange's FAQ pages on this topic to try and figure out how to get a question I asked out of "on hold". Still confused, I came here to ask for more clarity.

I'm still not sure **how** to go about getting my question unheld, or if I need to  do anything more.*

There are **two** answers I am seeking:

1. How to unhold a question that has been placed on hold by a moderator?
2. Is there anything else I can/should do to get my question off hold (I'm considering just deleting and re-asking it at this point)?

Comment: a tip: NEVER delete and re-ask. Especially if the first question was downvoted. That way lies a posting ban...

Comment: Well, having a question "on hold" with no way to get it unheld is essentially the same thing as a posting ban anyway.

Comment: The problem here seems to be you're asking here why questions are closed on specific sites, you'd be better asking on the DIY meta site for example. FWIW my most active site is Electrical Engineering and while the question would be off-topic there I can't work out what you're asking either. A diagram of how things are connected together would probably help.

Comment: I'm not trying to ask *why* the question was closed. Rather, I'm asking what can I do to get *any* closed question on *any* SE site re-opened. There are instructions, but when followed they do not have an immediate affect and there is zero feedback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Question OFF hold?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234047/how-to-get-a-question-off-hold)

Comment: Not a dupe of that closed question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Once a question that has been put on hold has been edited, it is placed in a reopen queue, for peers to review and (if deemed good enough), reopen.

It may be that the edits have not improved the question to the degree that it will get reopened.

---

I mentioned to the Community Team that the help center documentation on this could probably use some love in regards to "next steps".

Comment: Makes sense, but after editing there is no feedback whatsoever. I *still* don't know if I need to be more specific (I hesitate to make it too specific because then it could be "on hold" for that, instead).

Comment: the on-hold question that sparked this meta question: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44029/installing-two-germicidal-uv-systems-in-one-unit, if interested.

Comment: The help center may indeed need some more work, clarifying "next steps".

Comment: Oded, put that comment in the answer and i'll accept. :-)

Answer (score 7):

As per Oded's answer they go into a queue for peer review. People can leave a comment to why they're voting to leave something closed but it's optional and mostly not done. Sometimes I do if I think a question is "almost there", conversely sometimes I leave a comment if I think someone is likely to be wasting their time because while they may be making the question clearer it will still be off-topic for another reason.

During the review process comments are visible, so it may help to add a constructive and engaged sounding  comment like "I'm trying to address all problems with this question, can someone provide further guidance on other aspects that I may need to address?".

If that fails and after giving it as much thought as you can if you can't work out the reason really the next step is to ask on the per-site meta if there's a way to improve it. Once again keep it polite and constructive, others may even agree that it shouldn't have been closed in the first place and put a re-open vote on it. But if not you should hopefully get feedback on what can be improved and the underlying reason(s) it was put on hold which can vary subtly across sites.