# Reposting deleted questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions, reopen-closed, undelete

I asked a question, and it got deleted. I do not have enough reputation points to vote to reopen. What can I do if I still want the answer to the question?

I can't even edit the question to try to make it clearer, because it is deleted. I know I can ask it on a separate Stack Exchange site, but I fear the same thing will happen there.

Comment: Was it deleted or just closed? If it was deleted it would have been put on hold first, giving you a chance to edit and improve the question. Unless there was serious problems with the question you should have had ample time to improve it to a state where it could be reopened (it is automatically put in a reopen queue if you edit).

Comment: @Cai both. the problem is, it was closed because it was unclear. However, I did not understand how it was unclear. I had edited it a few times already, but it stayed closed. I didn't know how to change it to make it better. so i stopped editing it.

Comment: Well, if you just re-post it without fixing it, the second question is almost certain to meet the same fate.

Answer (score 9):

If your question was deleted then it would have, before being deleted, been put on hold for a number of days—specifically to give you a chance to improve your question to a state where it can be reopened. If you edit your question while it is on hold it will automatically be entered in to a queue where users with sufficient reputation will review the question and decide wether to reopen it or leave it closed.

If you are unsure of why your question was closed or how to improve your question you should reach out to users of that specific site. Regular users of the specific site you are asking on will be familiar with what is and isn't on-topic and what is considered a good question.

- Comment on the question itself asking for clarification and guidance (you can @reply to anyone who has previously commented to notify them).
- Assuming you have sufficient reputation (20) you can ask in that sites chat. This is the best option as you can discuss the issue without being limited to a Q&A format or comments.
- Bring the issue up on *that site's* meta—explaining why you disagree with the closure. Ask for guidance and clarification but don't be confrontational, you're unlikely to get much help by telling people their decision was wrong.

Asking here with no reference to the question isn't going to get you very far—the only thing anyone here can tell you (without knowing the specifics) is: Improve your question. Reposting the same question in the same state it was before it was closed isn't going to go down well. It will certainly be closed again and will frustrate users who saw it the first time round.

So in future, improve your question *before* it gets deleted. In this case, ask the question again *only* if you can clarify and improve on the original.

---

Related Help Center pages:

- [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)
- [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Related Meta FAQ Post:

- [How do you challenge the closing of one of your questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/how-do-you-challenge-the-closing-of-one-of-your-questions)