# How to contest a gold badge duplicate closure as low-rep user?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, dupehammer

I asked [Assign name to Hyper-V guest for Windows 10 host?](https://superuser.com/questions/1471239/assign-name-to-hyper-v-guest-for-windows-10-host) to get a constructive response to the problem on how to get a host name for a client VM known to the host.

Another user then came by and closed as duplicate. Being a gold badge holder this took effect immediately. I suspect they did so without understanding the question fully.

Now I've tried to reopen and call moderator attention to this question, so I can get an actual response perhaps even a useful answer, but without prevail.

How should I approach this from here?

---

EDIT:  The duplicate has been removed, without me getting to editing the question as suggested.

Comment: Asking the same question on meta.su would do the trick. Granted, you did get my attention...  but I'm sure with a good arguement that it wasn't a dupe, you'd have folks voting to reopen

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Oh.  I just clicked the Meta-link in the right side.  Didn't notice this was the stackexchange and not superuser meta.

Answer (score 5):

The procedure is basically identical to [How do you challenge the closing of one of your questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19126/295232) – basically, *edit* the question to indicate why the answers to the original question don't apply to your case. Since it was closed single-handledly, you can ['ping'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/295232) the gold tag badge holder with a comment to ask for a reevaluation of their decision (preferably *after* editing the question).

If you suspect somebody is *frequently* using their dupehammer wrongly, you might want to get the ♦ moderators involved via a custom moderator flag. But one closed question doesn't really warrant that.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I approach this from here?

Simply the same as you would  approach *duplicate votes* from flags as well.

Edit and improve your question, and explain why the duplicate doen't apply.